# como implementar jsPanel com jsf

Tags: javascript, jsp, xhtml, dialog, modal

Estou tentando renderizar uma pagina xhtml dentro jsPanel, mas so me volta o jsPanel vazio. 
este é o javascript:

```
function executeLoad(aUrl){

$.jsPanel({
    load:{
        url: aUrl
    },
    selector: "#content",
    title: "com url",    
    bootstrap: 'primary',


});
```

}

no xhtml
faco a chamada

```
<p:menuitem value="Lista Tipo Grupo" onclick="executeLoad('../sisger/TipoGrupo/sisgerTipoGru/List.xhtml')" />
```

me retorna:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no inspetor de objetos do chrome so aparece o codiogo original sem renderização.

Answer (score 1):

Depende da versão que você está usando. No caso a option "load" foi substituída por "contentAjax" que recebe um array json de dados, incluíndo a url de destino. Segue um exemplo jsPanel v3.0.0

```
function executeLoad(aUrl){

$.jsPanel({
    contentAjax: {
    url:      aUrl, // exemplo de url: '../media/files/exampleAjax.html'
    autoload: true
},
    headerTitle: 'Título da Janela',
    contentSize: {width: 470, height: 340},
    position:    {my: "center-top", at: "center-top"},
    theme:       'lightblue',
});

}
```

Comment: Seria interessante você explicar o que mudou no código e como ele funciona agora, pra resposta ficar mais completa e util pra quem cair nessa pergunta apos uma pesquisa :)